# Motor Shield Enable and Input Pins

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-motor-shield

[image: Motor Shield]

Hello,

I am new to the Arduino UNO board and am trying to make a dc motor run using the MATLAB software. The motor is connected to the motor shield board in a similar way shown in the picture below (taken from another question asked here). It runs use the IDE software with the motor shield library but I would like it to run it on MATLAB. I am not able to find out what enable pin, input A and input B for any of the motors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The working code from Arduino IDE examples:

```cpp
// Adafruit Motor shield library
// copyright Adafruit Industries LLC, 2009
// this code is public domain, enjoy!

#include <AFMotor.h>

AF_DCMotor motor(4);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);           // set up Serial library at 9600 bps
  Serial.println("Motor test!");

  // turn on motor
  motor.setSpeed(200);
 
  motor.run(RELEASE);
}

void loop() {
  uint8_t i;
  
  Serial.print("tick");
  
  motor.run(FORWARD);
  for (i=0; i<255; i++) {
    motor.setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
 }
 
  for (i=255; i!=0; i--) {
    motor.setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
 }
  
  Serial.print("tock");

  motor.run(BACKWARD);
  for (i=0; i<255; i++) {
    motor.setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
 }
 
  for (i=255; i!=0; i--) {
    motor.setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
 }
  

  Serial.print("tech");
  motor.run(RELEASE);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: please copy the working code and paste it into your question

Comment: Thank you for having a look at this issue. I pasted the working code to the question.

Comment: you almost had the code formatting correct ... the code delimiter is ```

Comment: the motor shield uses a shift register to control the motors ... the arduino GPIO pins are not connected directly to the motor driver